# QML: How to display a "<" character in a richTextBox?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml, syntax

The code in question:

```
description.insert(0,"<tr><td><H1>
      ---Less-Than-Sign-Here---           </H1></td><td><font face='Ubuntu'size='3'color='#f37420'>
IgnoreMe</font></td></tr><tr><td><font face='Ubuntu Mono' size='3' color='#8b0059'>
IgnoreMe</td><td>
IgnoreMe</td></tr>")
```

Trying to place a < in ---Less-Than-Sign-Here--- has not been displaying anything. I have tried doing an \< , but that hasn't worked either.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
&lt;
```

[There](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) is a useful site with signs codes.